# Accessing the AssetManager in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, assets, xamarin.forms

In **Xamarin Forms**, in a Dependency Service, I need to access an Asset.

How do I get the **AssetManager** from within a Dependency Service?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using `Forms.Context.Assets`.  It will return an AssetManager.

Comment: And the correct answer, in fact.  Thank you very much.  I found a reference to it in the Xamarin documentation but it should probably be made more obvious.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach now looks to be [deprecated](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/658f32159956c5632271a841a698f919c8db42a2/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Forms.cs#L34). The alternate approach of `Android.App.Application` returns a different type of context (app vs. activity, I think) where Assets isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an implicit import in `Xamarin.Forms` that adds `Forms.Context.Assets` to the scope.

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

.... 

AssetManager assets = Forms.Context.Assets;
string content;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assets.Open("AboutAssets.txt")))
{
  content = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(content.Length);
```